# Cannot find module 'http' (caused by @types/cors)

Tags: angular, typescript

The error was caused by updating Angular, Material, and libraries that depend on Angular.

Error:

> Error: node_modules/@types/cors/index.d.ts:8:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http' or its corresponding type declarations.
> import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';

- Angular: 14.1.3
- @types/node dev dependency: 18.7.13
- typescript: 4.6.4

The error is caused by @types/cors/index.d.ts

I do not directly depend on this, it's coming from the dependency tree of @angular-devkit/build-angular (14.1.3).

I tried the following solutions already:

- Add typeRoots and types to compilerOptions in tsconfig.json
- Update the relevant libraries, trying multiple versions
- The StackOverflow answer I found, which was basically just to install @types/node
- Removing and re-installing node_modules
- Downgrading Node.js to 16.10.0

Comment: Facing the same error via `socket.io@4.5.4 > engine.io@6.2.1 > @types/cor@2.8.13 > @types/node@18.11.17`

Comment: @geekay I never found a solution for this besides setting skipLibCheck to false

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the following setting in tsconfig compilerOptions:

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

Comment: Surely this will skip the check and prevent the compile-time error, but mind that `Http` was renamed to `HttpClient` in Angular 4, are you sure that the library you're using is compatible? If the library is compatible, maybe the type definition is wrong, you should `npm uninstall @types/cors` and eventually re-install it (if available)

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina The error in my original post shows that the 'cors' module is looking for the native Node.js 'http' module, the error is not specifically related to the Angular libraries you mentioned.

Comment: Ok clear, actually I don't know the lib so I suppose it was requiring the `Http` module of Angular